# Distance from linear functional to annihilator of closed subspace of Banach space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Let $E$ be a Banach space and $G \subset E$ a closed subspace of $E$. In a proof somewhere in Brezis's book, he claims that:

$$\operatorname{dist}(f, G^{\perp}) = \sup\{f(x) \ \vert \ x \in G, \|x\| \leq 1 \}$$

where we define $G^{\perp} = \{f \in E^{*} \ \vert \ f(x) = 0 \ \forall x \in G \}$. I'm having trouble seeing why this is true.

Here's what I tried: since $G^{\perp}$ is closed, there exists (because of Hahn-Banach) $h \in G^{\perp}$ such that:

$$\operatorname{dist}(f, G^{\perp}) = \|f - h\| $$

And therefore:
$$\operatorname{dist}(f, G^{\perp})= \sup\{ |f(x) - h(x)| \ \vert \ x \in G, \|x\| \leq 1\} = \sup\{|f(x)| \ \vert \ x \in G, \|x\| \leq 1\}$$

This is almost what I wanted, but there's an absolute value missing. I don't think both the book and I can be right simultaneously, so did I make a mistake somewhere here? Or what is it that I'm missing?

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Since $G\cap B_E$ is  symmetric,  $\sup_{x \in G \cap B_E} |φ(x)| =\sup_{x \in G \cap B_E} φ(x)$ for every functional $φ$. (Here $B_E$ is the closed unit ball of $E$)

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF. That's true! Thanks so much, can't believe I missed something that silly.